# inputText data is not displayed in value

Tags: jsf

Datatable:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:dataTable id="branch-table" value="#{testController.items}" var="item" border="0" >
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="NAME"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
            </h:column> 
            <h:column>
                <h:inputText value="#{item.name}"/>
            </h:column> 
            <h:column>
                <p:commandButton styleClass="edit" action="#{testController.prepareEdit}" value="" oncomplete="updateForm();"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

form:

```
<div id="test-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <h:form>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            Details
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h:inputText value="#{testController.edit.name}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <p:commandButton action="#{testController.update}" value="#{bundle.CreateBranchSaveLink}"/>
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <p:remoteCommand name="updateForm" update="@form" oncomplete="$('#test-modal').modal('show');"/>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

prepareEdit method:

```
public void prepareEdit() {
    current = (TestEntity) getItems().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
}
```

edit method:

```
public TestEntity getEdit() {
    if (editCurrent == null) {
        editCurrent = new TestEntity();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
    }
    return editCurrent;
}
```

notice `<h:inputText value="#{testController.edit.name}"/>` on the form. no data will be displayed, but if i change it to `<h:outputText value="#{testController.edit.name}"/>` , correct data will be displayed.

i'm confused is to why is this. i need it to be inputText so i can update it with the new value.

*updated

getItems method:

```
public DataModel getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: If you debug the getter method of `#{testController.edit.name}` are you going through it?

Comment: yes, both for inputText and outputText. it will pass through it

Comment: provide your controller code especially (testController.items) data